# Reverse order of a string

Tags: bash

I want to "reverse" the order of the four octets (bytes) that make up an ip address.

Suppose I have this ip:

```
202.168.56.32
```

I need to convert into:

```
32.56.168.202
```

and then ultimately remove the first octet in the reversed ip. Final result:

```
56.168.202
```

My attempts:

```
echo 202.168.56.32 | rev
```

But it's returning :

```
23.65.861.202
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo 202.168.56.32|awk -F. '{print $3"."$2"."$1}'
```

You could also do it with bash arrays:

```
ip=202.168.56.32
parts=(${ip//./ })
echo ${parts[2]}.${parts[1]}.${parts[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use sed.

```
echo 202.168.56.32 | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)/\4.\3.\2.\1/g'
```